# Correct SQL Statement for Joining Taxonomy Terms

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, database

I have 2 different taxonomy vocabularies setup.

1. Courses (First Aid, H2S Alive, Air Monitoring, Gas Detection,
   etc...)
2. Locations (Vancouver, Calgary, Toronto, Montreal)

I have a content type called **Landing Page** for each of the courses that has a taxonomy reference field so you can assign a course or multiple courses to that node.

I have a second content type for **Courses** which also has the 2 taxonomy vocabularies set as taxonomy reference fields on its nodes. These course nodes get displayed in a calendar format and is setup with the entity registration module.

**WHAT I NEED HELP WITH:**

Im looking for a way to output a set of buttons on the **Landing Page** nodes that will give me a the list of locations that have been assigned to any node that is based on the given Courses taxonomy term.

For example;

3 Different **Courses** nodes all have **First Aid** assigned to them. However, they have 3 different locations set to them.

I've created a landing page for the **First Aid** Course assigned it the First Aid taxonomy term. I need to display a set of locations that this course has courses offered at.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show Locations a Course is offered. Or Courses at a Location I would recommend using the [Views Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field) module, or perhaps Context to show a View on the content type page.

Views field allows you send parameters to the embedded field view from the source Node. So you should be able to get the related content(s) you want to show by passing the necessary filter parameter criteria you want to the View -- usually as a `contextual filter`.

For example for a Landing Page Content Type (eg, First Aid) you add a field that is a View. Call the view like `locations for course`. Then make a View that outputs Location taxonomy term names based on a contextual filters. The contextual filter will be:

- the taxonomy term name of the course(s) in your taxonomy of Courses.

Then output the taxonomy Location term names for results of the set course name contextual filter. Overwrite the linkpath as needed.

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer. I'm still a bit unsure about how I can relate the 2 taxonomies based on the fact that I need to check to see if nodes from a different content type have the specific course assigned to it. 

Basically I could have 100 courses only being offered at 2 locations. I need to pull those 2 locations into my other content type that is related by my 1 course taxonomy field.

I tried to setup the Views Field module and have it setup on the settings page but I'm still unclear about what I need to setup in my view to have this working together.

Comment: You want contextual filters and "Relationships" under Views Advanced settings tab for the View. For instance you make a Relationship for Nodes tagged as a specific Course term name. Then under Fields output the Location values for those related nodes, and remove duplicates. What you want is a little tricky in the Views UI (understanding all the pieces), but doable I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

In views you can add a relationship to emulate an sql join. In the relationship you define the field that you want to use for this join. The cool thing is that a relatioship has a name. So when you add a field to display you can use this relatioship. Eg if you add 
field_sometag it displays the fields of your base entity. But when select to use the relationship then the field displays info about the joined entity

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I was able to get the correct settings in my Answer below. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Alright I finally figured it out with the help of @tenken. I didn't end up needing any extra modules except the [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module to reduce my duplicates as the regular aggregation and DISTINCT items weren't working (assuming it was due to the fact that I had the relationship in there). I was able to relate it through the relationships and the default views.

Heres how I did it;

[image: View Overview]

And the field settings. Its imperative you use Content: All Taxonomy Terms with the "node" relationship applied to it.

[image: Views Content: All Taxonomy Terms field settings]

And Finally the Views Distinct Module settings.

[image: Views Distinct Module settings]